# FormulaR1C1 from another WorkBook

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking at this code for a while and can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong. It must be one of those obvious solutions, but I'm stumped.

The line of code that's causing me trouble is this:

`Range("M2:M5759).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(isna(vlookup(RC[-12], " & Path & "[Budget " & Month & ".xlsx]Budget_" & Month & "'!RC[-12]:R[LastR]C[-12], 1, false)), ""NO"", ""YES"")"`

The variable Path contains the location of the file I'm looking at.

The name of the file is Budget 0615.xlsx, and the Tab is named Budget_0615, but the date has to be changeable, so it is assigned to the variable Month.

The variable LastR contains the number of rows in the file.

My code is trying to return the value "NO" if the value in column A can't be found in the file Budget 0615.xlsx, and return "YES" if it can.

When I run the Macro, I get the Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Can someone help? If you need more info or if I'm not being clear, just ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing a ' before the `Path` in the formula, and `LastR` needs to be concatenated into the formula string as an absolute, not relative, number:

```
Range("M2:M5759).FormulaR1C1 = "=if(isna(vlookup(RC[-12],'" & Path & "[Budget " & Month & ".xlsx]Budget_" & Month & "'!RC[-12]:R" & LastR & "C[-12], 1, false)), ""NO"", ""YES"")"
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally didn't see my missing '. After reading your answer I also realised that for what I was trying to achieve, not only did LastR need to be an absolute, but the whole range I was calling.